# Nagios not sending emails when a service recovers?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have set up Nagios with chef. It's accurately monitoring things. When a service/host has a problem, I get an email and jabber message, which is exactly how I have configured it.

However when the service/host recovers, I don't get anything. No email or jabber message. The nagios website updates to show that the service/host is OK, I just got no recovery emails. My nagios website lists the notifications it's sent, and they are all problem notifications. There is no record there of any recovery emails.

What can cause this? Is there a different nagios setting for `recovery_notification_command`?

Comment: Is the service showing as flapping?

Comment: Can you post the `notification_options` of the hosts/templates/contacts? It has to contain `r` for recovery.

Comment: @MadHatter No, the service is not flapping. This problem (no recovery notifications) has existed for months and there are no notifcations for any of the dozen+ service problems there has been (slighly noisy nagios)

Comment: @Halfgaar I think that was it! :) There was no `r` in the `notification_options`. I've added that, and will confirm if it works. Please make a proper answer, so that I can upvote/accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, you don't have `r` in the `notification_options` in your host config, host template, contact config, etc. If nagios doesn't even show `recovery` notifications in the logs, this is likely it.

BTW, for hosts, one of the options is `u`. That doesn't mean `up` as you might expect, it means `unreachable`, a special state when a host's parent is down. You can opt to choose not to receive those, because if your router is down, you know that everything below it is down too. This is unrelated to you question, but perhaps good to know :)

Comment: in version 4.4.1 and later, now you have to include the f (flapping) in order to get the email when it is back ok.

Comment: Note to future googlers: `notification_options` example can be found [here](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html).

Comment: @majed do you have a link to any documentation around your flapping explanation?  I have flapping disabled everywhere and am still not receiving RECOVERY/UP notifications for hosts.

Comment: @majed nevermind; I don't have any issues related to flapping (and I do not have "f" enabled).  My issue was that "HOSTPROBLEMID" was "0" and that I needed to use "LASTHOSTPROBLEMID".